# How to keep check mark after dismissing a tableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a filter tableview with single selection enabled by showing the check mark icon for selected row. Once the back button clicked it will take to the home tableview where I am loading list of items. There is a filter button in the home VC . When I click on that I want to show the check mark on previously selected row of the filter tableview. How can I do that? Thank you in advance
This is the filter table which I want to show the checkmark icon
[image]

I want to see check mark again after dismissing a tableView in swift

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you want to saved the latest state of the filter, make sure you update the models and saved it to a cache, not only update the UI.

For example, you have a model like this:

```
struct Filter { let name: String, var isSelected: Bool}
```

so in you view controller you have list of `[Filter]`. When you updating the row you need to update the selected object too.

Example:

```
var filters: [Filter] = [...., ....]

func tableView(... didSelectRow ... ) {
// update UI
// update the list 
filters[indexPath.row].isSelected = true / false 
// Update the Cache here
}
```

and if you want to keep it consistent each time you back/route to the FilterController you need to save it in some cache like UserDefaults/CoreData/etc. So every time you enter the FilterController make sure too fetch the latest updated data from the cache, and update the UI according to cache data.

Comment: You also need to set the proper `accessoryType` on each cell in `cellForRowAt`.